# PC overheating at very low CPU usage

Tags: cpu, fan, cooling, cpu-usage, temperature

My PC has started overheating really quickly while seemingly maintaining low CPU usage. In idle it usually sits around 50-60°C and maintains a temperature around 70-80°C while doing simple things. Sometimes it will randomly spike to 100+°C while CPU usage stays below 10% and not cool down again.

The fans start blasting at full speed but the temperature stays this high. Then slowly the CPU usage seems to increase and it will start lagging.

I have a prebuilt MSI `MEG Infinite X 11th` with a watercooling system that I did not tamper with at all. I cleaned the fans with a vaccuum yesterday but this issue persists.

Comment: Are you able to reseat the CPU with a thin layer of thermal paste?  It may have dried out.

Comment: I have never tampered with that and I don't think I have thermal paste. But I will look into that, thanks

Comment: its also possible that your pump has gone out. water cooling isn't very active unless the water is moving.

Comment: `I don't think I have thermal paste` .. I bet you do indeed have thermal paste.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - To your observation they likely DO have thermal paste.  If they actually didn't have thermal paste, the processor likely would overheat instantly, and the PC would automatically shutdown within a few seconds due to the heat. I suspect the problem is indeed the water pump.  11th generation processor implies a device that is at least 2 years old.

Comment: Agreed @Ramhound .. I was trying to be gentle. :P